# Crud real time SSE?

Tags: javascript, php, server-sent-events

Can i perform crud with `SSE` real time when user add something to database or update to show to all users which are connected, i want to know if i can do this thing by using php or i go with javascript, because i want to build a admin panel where administrator adding a blog post and if users are on blog to display them in real time.
Thank you!

```
var source = new EventSource("real.php");
    source.onmessage = function(event) {
        var jdata = JSON.parse(event.data);
        console.log(jdata);
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += jdata.firstName + "<br>";
    };
```

This is my testing js and this one is php:

```
<?php 
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

$data = array(
'firstName'=>'Test',
'lastName'=>'Last'
 );
 $str = json_encode($data);
 echo "data: {$str}\n\n";
 flush();
 ?>
```

Right now this example is just adding to `#result` html over and over, i want to detect when is something new in database then append to html new thing added in real time.

Answer (score 0):

Sure,

in order for this to work you will need an event-log which loggs every operation you want to track. Add row to `event_log` for every operation you want to track.

Minimal example (fictional data) - stored in a table(e.g. `event_log`):

```
[
    'timestamp' => 1,
    'table' => 'user'
    'id' => '99',
    'action' => 'create'
    'data' => [...]
],[
    'timestamp' => 1234,
    'table' => 'posts',
    ...
]
```

Now every time your `real.php` gets called, you query your `event_log` having entries newer than the last time you checked. In order to do this your php-script would look like this:

```
<?php
// disable buffering to receive output immediately
ini_set('output_buffering','off'); 

header("Content-Type: text/event-stream");
$lastChecked = time(); // save current timestamp

while (true) // runs until connection gets terminated
{
    // query event_log where time > $lastChecked
    // echo accoring to link provided
   
    // reset lastChecked
    $lastChecked = time();

    // wait 1 second before checking event_log again
    sleep(1);
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events#Fields

SSE example: https://github.com/mdn/dom-examples/blob/master/server-sent-events/sse.php

After you received the event via `onmessage` you will have to use JS to add/edit or remove elements of the DOM to make these changes visible for the user.

You may want to use event specific handlers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events#Named_events

in JS:

```
source.addEventListener('<your_event_name>', function(event) { /** event.data ... */ })
```